Acceleration-time graph to travel 1 meter in 1 second and eventually reach 0 velocity and 0 acceleration
How do I go about getting an equation of acceleration in terms of time such that an object travels $1$ meter in $1$ second, given that:

At $t = 0.5$, the acceleration is $0$ and the velocity is unknown
At $t = 1$, the velocity and acceleration is $0$.

Is it possible to derive such an equation starting from $a = \mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}t$?

This is a question for the physics stackexchange

The structure of this question looks a lot like a homework problem.  If it is a homework problem, can you edit this to add in what you have tried so far?  Then we can tailor the answer to where you are stumped. Also, as the first answer suggests, there's actually not enough information to come up with one-and-only-one equation for acceleration.  There are many acceleration profiles that fit the constraints given.  Another limit such as "acceleration varies quadratically" or "acceleration is piecewise linear" would further restrict the answers.

@CortAmmon Since the guidance for the HW tag is "A "homework question" is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved rather than getting the answer itself", I've tagged this as HW as part of my edit.

I also was unsure if it was homework, but I decided that since there wasn't a unique answer that it was more likely not homework. But I certainly admit that it is borderline, and reasonable people could assume that it is.

this is not a homework question, i am trying to get a better understanding of derivatives in physics, and thought that a= dv/dt is something a lot of people are familiar with

You have an unknown acceleration $\ddot x$ and two boundary conditions $x(0)=0$ and $x(1)=1$. So this is a 2nd order differential equation. You need the solution to that differential equation to meet the following additional requirements: $$\ddot x(0.5)=0$$$$\ddot x(1)=0$$$$\dot x(1)=0$$
So, we have three equations and we will therefore need $\ddot x$ to have three unknown parameters. Since we are not given any other restrictions, we can simply choose a polynomial $\ddot x$. To have three unknown parameters then we will need to choose at least a 2nd order polynomial: $$\ddot x = c_2 t^2+c_1 t + c_0$$ Solve the original differential equation with its boundary conditions, then solve the three additional requirements equations for the three unknown $c_i$.
It is possible that there is no solution with all real $c_i$. In that case try $$\ddot x = c_3 t^3+ c_2 t^2 + c_1 t$$ and so forth.
